# TSqlObject has no ContextObject property?

Tags: visual-studio, t4, sql-server-data-tools, envdte

I'm attempting to create a T4 template that generates source code for calling stored procedures that are contained in another project in my solution. I am able to successfully enumerate the .sql files in the solution, add them to a `TSqlModel`, and use that model to retrieve the list of stored procedures as `TSqlObject` instances. Now, I need to enumerate the parameters for each stored procedure, and this is where I'm getting hung up.

When I debug my template, I can see that the `TSqlObject` instances have a `ContextObject` property, and this property contains, among other things, the list of parameters that I need to generate my code. When I attempt to access this property from my template, however, the compiler complains that the property doesn't exist:

> Error 1   Compiling transformation: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlObject' does not contain a definition for 'ContextObject' and no extension method 'ContextObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   d:\Code\cs\test_sproccodegen\CallingProject\sproc_template.tt   34  111 CallingProject

I can definitely access this `ContextObject` property from the Immediate window while debugging, but it is not available at compile time.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.tsqlobject_properties.aspx You sure you're not accessing a private/internal/protected property?

Comment: It's listed in the Locals window, and it works just fine in the Immediate window. Would those work for a private property?

Comment: Possibly.  I don't use either, but if you view an instance in the quick watch window you can browse all properties, no matter the access modifier.

Comment: In the screenshot, it's clear it's not private.

Comment: It's internal.  [Boom!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ibQeM.png)  That's version 10, but it's also internal in 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property isn't listed [in the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.tsqlobject_properties.aspx), which probably means it's internal or private.  Only public and protected accessible members are included in the docs.

Checking it out in JustDecompile, you can see it is, in fact, *internal*.

[image: boom, internal]

Answer (score 1):

That's an internal method as mentioned by Will in the question comments. You should use the public APIs instead. The following documenation should help you get started:

- [Model API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.aspx)
- [Public Model Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/12/23/dacfx-public-model-tutorial.aspx)
- [Dac samples project](http://dacsamples.codeplex.com/). There aren't any T4 template examples but it has a lot of examples of querying and even manipulating the model. You just need to put that in T4 template form.

Comment: As mentioned by Mark?  Lol, nice try, short stack.

Comment: Sorry Will, answered too quickly! Just wanted to give Mark some context on how to proceed without accessing the internal method and it's easier to link in an answer :)

Comment: Kevin, you definitely nailed the REAL problem I was trying to solve, but Will answered this particular question (apparently, VS during debug doesn't mark internal methods any differently than public, as opposed to private, which have the little lock icon), so I gave him credit.

Comment: No problem at all, Will definitely got the right answer in for the question.